# I am new to programming and I am having trouble making Cards with Suits assigned to them for a BlackJack Game

Tags: java, blackjack

I am making a BlackJack game but i got a little stuck on how to make a deck with proper suits... My first thought was to have something like 
int[] cards ={1, 2, etc etc etc};
but then I couldn't figure out how to implement suits with those cards

Now I know my code is far from finished, I still need to have hands and many other things but I would like to first learn how to make Cards and Suits before I move on

Basically my question is: How can I make a Deck of Cards with suits and use them for my Black Jack game Also if you explain to me how and why it works that would be great since I am trying to learn java programming.

### MY CODE

```
package blackjack2;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class blackjackattemp2 {
    final static String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int playersValue = 0, dealersValue = 0, bet = 0, money = 0;
    static boolean win;
    static char hit;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How much money would you like to start with?: ");
    money = reader.nextInt();
    if(money < 0){
        System.out.print("You are out of money!" + NL + "You lose!");
    }

    }   
    public static void hit(char hit){
        while(hit == 'y'){

        }
    }
    static void testWin(boolean testWin){
        if(playersValue > 21 || dealersValue >= playersValue && dealersValue <= 21){
        win = false;
    }
        if(dealersValue > 21 || playersValue <= 21 && playersValue >= dealersValue){
            win = true;
        }


    }
    static void moneyCalc(){
        if(win == true){
            money = money + bet;
        }
        if(win == false){
            money = money - bet;
        }
    }
    static void deck(){

    }

    }
```

---

I was thinking of how i would add cards to a users hand and I came up with this, It worked in my first version of my Black Jack game but I don't think it will now...

```
System.out.println("You get a " + cards[0] + " and a " + cards[1]);
cardValue = cards[0] + cards[1];
System.out.println("Your total is " + cardValue);
```

I would appreciate it greatly if someone were to tell me how I could change my old code to work for the new game of which I am creating.

Comment: Make a class called `Card` and let it have the attributes of a card (a value, a suit, etc...) then you can make an array of them like this `Card[]`.

Comment: Well the problem is that i haven't the slightest clue how to give it the attributes of a card

Comment: `int value` which could be 2 - 14 (11-14 are jack-ace) and `String suit` which would be either "Hearts" "Diamonds" "Spades" or "Clubs". That's it. Then just make a constructor in the Card class take these as parameters so you make new cards like this `Card c = new Card(2, "Hearts")`

Comment: Alright, so instead of Card c = new Card(2, "Hearts") could i put Card c = new Card(value, "suit")   and have it pull a random number and suit?

Comment: If you look at the answer I posted you will see what I mean. If you want to get a random card from the deck you should probably shuffle the order of the cards in the array, then pull the cards out in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the object oriented nature of the language. A card in a deck is a self contained entity so you can replicate that by making a class to hold the attributes that you want (a card's value and suit).

Here is an example of a Card class.

```
public class Card {
    private int value;
    private String suit;

    public Card(int value, String suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public int getValue() { return this.value; }
    public String getSuit() { return this.suit; }
}
```

You can use this to make a deck in your Blackjack program like this (Note: you could also make a Deck class as well which would allow you to make blackjack games with multiple decks and other advantages)

```
public class Blackjack {
    private Card[] deck;

    public Blackjack() {
        deck = new Card[52]; // Makes an array which holds 52 Card objects
        deck[0] = new Card(2, "Hearts");
        deck[1] = new Card(3, "Hearts");
        deck[2] = new Card(4, "Hearts");
        deck[3] = new Card(5, "Hearts");
        // And so on
    }
}
```

Now as you can see this would result in a long list of you making each card individually. You can improve this by making your cards in a loop, but I will leave that task to you. This should get you started on your way though.

Now once you have a deck of cards you can shuffle them around. There are many easy ways to do this. After the deck is shuffled you can deal them out 1 by 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2D Array, these are very similar to arrays, but it is an array inside of an array.

for your case, if you would like to store the cards inside of an array, do this

```
final int decks[][] = { {1,2,3 etc...} {deck2} {deck3} {deck4} };
```

To access the contents

```
for (int deck = 0; deck < decks.length; deck ++) {
    for (int card = 0; card < decks[deck].length; card++) {
        int yourCard = decks[deck][card];
    }
}
```

That will cycle through every piece of data in that array

However this seems to be efficient if you are not familiar with creating objects. If so, the above answer will suit you, as it creates a card object each time by stating the suit of the card, and the card number